# How to prevent document_scanner_flutter from saving cropped image in gallery in Flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, file, package

How can I prevent document_scanner_flutter from saving the cropped file in the gallery after scanning an image in my Flutter app? I am currently using file.delete() to delete the file from the gallery, but there is still a placeholder left in the gallery. After researching, I found that Android has a cache of sorts that keeps track of media files and running the MediaScanner service again can solve the issue. However, the solution I found involves native code and I have little knowledge of it. Is there a way to solve this issue using Dart, or is there another way to prevent the cropped file from being saved in the gallery?

Here is my code for capturing the image using document_scanner_flutter package:

```
try {
  imagePicked = await DocumentScannerFlutter.launch(
    context,
  );
  if (imagePicked != null) {
    setState(() {
      onUpload(imagePicked);
    });
  }
} on PlatformException {
  debugPrint('Failed to get document path or operation cancelled!');
}
```

and to delete the file i called delete method of file
`document.delete();`

Comment: after you delete the file you can use this library 
https://pub.dev/packages/media_scanner_scan_file
to fix problem of show deleted images in your gallery

Comment: i get this error " Unhandled Exception: type '_Map<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Map<String, dynamic>>' " when i call  MediaScannerScanFile.scanFile(image.path);